# Do probabilities (frequentist interpretation) always have to be rational numbers?

Tags: probability, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

in frequentist interpretation probability is defined as the ratio of positive outcomes over all outcomes.
Since positive outcomes and outcomes over all are count-data and therefor integers, they ratio between those two has to be a rational number.

Can we therefore conclude, that all true probabilities have to be rational numbers or other way round: a probability which is an irational number can not be true under a frequentist interpretation of probability?

Comment: Frequentist probabilities are a limit of proportions, so they are a limit of rational numbers, which does not need to be rational

Comment: The limit of rational numbers can still be irrational.  Consider an experiment where we pick a real number in the unit interval uniformly at random and we ask whether it was larger or smaller than $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.  Yes, after finitely many attempts it will have some number of them greater and another number of them less... but the limit as the number of attempts grows to infinity, the ratio of them who are less approaches the irrational number $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: thanks for your answers @rubikscube09 and JMoravitz. I think im strugling a bit with the part about the limit. In my understanding, if i continue a testing series to infinity i will still allways be an integer over an integer (since with each step the numerator will increase by 0 or 1 and the denomiator will increase by 1). So even if the limit would be squr(2)/2 we could not make a point-landing on this value? I see some contradiction here and don't see where im drifting of :(

Comment: Yes - you will never make a "point-landing on the value", instead, you will get a sequence of rational numbers that approaches an irrational number. Think about the following - you have a square with side length 2, and you inscribe a circle inside of it. The circle has area $\pi$, and the square are $4$. If you throw a dart at the square, what is the probability that it lands inside the circle? If you know the answer to that, what do you think will happen when you throw a very large number of darts at the square, and count the proportion inside?